# Button onclick attribute error

Tags: javascript, html, button

Hello i am having some technical issues with my HTML code and javascript so to begin.
i have the  `<P id="One">`and i need once you click the All courses input to redirect you to another page and completly disapear himself using javascript.

```
<p id="One" >

    <input type="button" onclick="allCourses()" value="All Courses" /> 
    <input type="button" onclick="" value="1st Year" />


 </p>
```

and the Javascript i am using is

```
function allCourses(){
  document.getElementById("One").innerHTML="";

  var input = document.createElement('button');
    var value = document.createTextNode("Go to Google");
  input.appendChild(value);
  //input.type = "button";
  //input.onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';
  //input.value="Go to Google";
  var element = document.getElementById("One");
  element.appendChild(input);

    }
     function Google(){
     location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';

    }
```

The button works like charm but as soon i attack the onclick attr it doesn't do nothing!

Comment: Or maybe you want it to be `input.onclick=function(){location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';}`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Immediately go to another page after clicking the first button? It would be one line of code.

Comment: thanks for the help the second anwser was the key!